# S3 bucket sensor for new file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, etl

I am working on an ETL pipeline using docker airflow. I want to trigger my pipeline whenever any new file is uploaded to S3 bucket.
Is there any S3sensor in airflow that checks any new file in bucket? The S3sensor should ignore the existing files in location and should only trigger when new file is added to S3.

Comment: You could use a lambda trigger on the S3 bucket to kick off your airflow pipeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options to achieve this goal:

- The best solution is creating [S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) on file creation to send a message to SQS. In Airflow you can create a [sensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/aws_sqs_sensor/index.html) to check if there are new messages to process them.
- You can also create a sensor which list the files in S3 bucket, and add them to a state store (DB for ex) with state `to_process`, the next time it will compares between the files list and the files in the state store to know it there are new files or not, then your dag process the records in the state store which have a state != `done`, and when it finish the processing, it updates the state to `done`. You can add other metadata like `created_at`, `processed_at`, and other states like `error` to reprocess them in the next run or send an alert to your team.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am trying the option1. I have created the SQS queue and with all the permission of s3 bucket. Now to use the airflow SQSSensor, I am not sure how to setup the connection for it. I couldn't find much resource. Could you help me?

Comment: you can create a new user with the permission `sqs:ReceiveMessage` on the new queue, then export the access and secret key and put them in an [AWS Airflow connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html). If your Airflow server is running on AWS EKS, you can use service accounts to do that

Comment: thank you so much. I was able to the connection. Only one thing I am struggling with, SQSSensor reads and deletes the messsage which gets pull through "xcom". I want to read the message for further scripts before it deletes the message.

Comment: in tho official sensor you cannot stop messages deleting, you can develop a new custom senosr using boto3